# Difference between "on sale" vs "on sales"

Tags: word-usage

Just saw a board that said "on sales".  Is it a correct usage when they have several items that goes on sale?

Comment: What was intended by "on sales"?

Comment: This sounds unusual. Can you tell us the full text of the board, or even upload a photo of it please?

Comment: A high street shop having a board outside announcing this unusual combination.

Comment: You can write a journal paper entitled "On Sales" to discuss the nature of sales, but that's quite different from selling items at a discount (*on sale*).

Comment: Perhaps the writer of the board was not a native English speaker and English was their second language. Maybe they meant to say the colloquial 'For sale'.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"On Sales" is not an idiomatic phrase which a native American English speaker would use to indicate that a product can be had for a reduced price, not even if multiple products were experiencing reduced pricing. "Eggs and milk are on sale" is an example, with "on sale" being correct even with multiple products affected.

There are other situations where "on sales" could be a correct thing to say. For example, a company building could label its floors by function rather than numerically, and a conversation could happen like this: "What floor is the meeting on?" "It's on Sales." It is also possible for the price-reducing meaning to be valid as a plural, such as "Three stores have sales going right now". It does not seem like the sign you saw is one of these though, and is more likely just a grammatical error.